# Athena / Presto table on top of multiple json in one line

Tags: amazon-athena, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am looking for ways to read Lambda logs that gets shipped to S3 via Athena. We use central logging as explained here, with minor variations. The flow is: `Lambda` -> `CloudWatch` -> `Subscription filter` -> `Kinesis Stream` -> `Kinesis Firehose` -> `S3`.

https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/centralized-logging/

The logs fall in a multiple JSON per line format. It is always one line and multiple JSON concatenated. No delimiter between the two json.

```
{"messageType":"DATA_MESSAGE","owner":"xxxx","logGroup":"/aws/lambda/xxx","logStream":"2021/07/16/[4]...... }]}{"messageType":"DATA_MESSAGE","owner":"xxxx","logGroup":"/aws/lambda/xxx","logStream":"2021/07/16/[4]......}]}
```

I tried to use org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe to read this JSON. But, as you would imagine it only parses out the first JSON. The second JSON that is concatenated to the first is totally ignored. No errors from the DDL, it just silently ignores.

https://github.com/yuki-mt/scripts/blob/a73076cbb3062dae2cf30ddbbe68f5293738264d/aws/athena/sample_queries.sql

Curious to see if anyone has encountered this requirement and solved it with a smart DDL? Not a lot of room to re-format the logs or look at different solutions. Restricted with S3 and Athena.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I had similar issue of getting all json records in one line with {{row 1}{row 2}{row 3}} format. I used '}{' to identify row end and split rows based on that. Of course, I used lambda to do it and happy to share code. Nonetheless, you are looking for out of box Athena solution, which I'm afraid may not exist or not a simple solution.

Comment: Thanks @Ash. I wish I could process the logs using Lambda and the likes. Looks like this is a dead end. Thanks.